# How can I optimize in the weight “w”?

Tags: calculus, optimization

If I have $f(x),x > 0$ where $g(x)$ is an upper bound of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ is a lower bound of $f(x)$, how can I optimize on the weight $w$ to approximate $f(x)$ in this way? 
$f(x) = w\cdot g(x) + (1-w)\cdot h(x).$

Comment: So, $f(x), h(x)$, and $g(x)$ are known and we further know that $h(x)\le f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x>0$?
Are these functions continuous? where do you want $f(x)=wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)$ happen exactly? on which interval or set?

Comment: Yes, f,g,h are continuous functions.I want to approximate f(x) in (0,inf) as a linear combination of an upper and lower bound, because f(x) cannot be expressed as a closed form. I want a method to find the best weight w so as  w*g(x) + (1-w)*h(x) is as close to f(x) as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to think about is minimizing the sum of distances of $wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)$ from $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and imposing $h(x)\le wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)\le g(x)$. This can be captured by 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{w\in \mathbb R} \quad & 
 \int_{0}^{\infty} |g(x)-wg(x)-(1-w)h(x)| dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} |wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)-h(x)| dx  \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad &  h(x)\le wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)\le g(x); \ \\ \forall x\in [0,\infty),               \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which reduces to the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{w\in \mathbb R} \quad & 
  \int_{0}^{\infty} |w-1|[g(x)-h(x)] dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} |w|[g(x)-h(x)] dx \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad &  h(x)\le wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)\le g(x); \ \ \forall x\in [0,\infty).              \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This further is equivalent to below:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{w\in \mathbb R} \quad & 
\int_{0}^{\infty} (|w-1|+|w|)[g(x)-h(x)] dx  \\
\textrm{subject to} \quad &  h(x)\le wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)\le g(x); \ \ \forall x\in [0,\infty).             \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In general, note that assuming $k(x)$ is continous on $[a,b]$, we have $\int_{a}^{b} |k(x)| dx=0$ iff $k(x)\equiv 0$, almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I cannot really understand how we can approximate f(x) with this method. You don't even use the arithmetic values of f(x).

Comment: For my answer, I assumed that we have no knowledge about $f(x)$ except that $f(x)\approx wg(x)+(1-w)h(x)$ and further it must be between its lower and upper bounds that are continuous. So, after finding $w^*$ using the above minimization, we let $f(x)=w^*g(x)+(1-w^*)h(x).$